# Why does this code sometimes return NaN?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, nan, math.h

This often returns NAN ("Not A Number") depending on input:

```
#define PI 3.1415f

GLfloat sineEaseIn(GLfloat ratio) {
 return 1.0f-cosf(ratio * (PI / 2.0f));
}
```

I tried making PI a few digits smaller to see if that would help. No dice. 
Then I thought it might be a datatype mismatch, but **float** and **glfloat** seem to be equivalent:

**gl.h**

```
typedef float           GLfloat;
```

**math.h**

```
extern float  cosf( float );
```

Is this a casting issue?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your casting. Could it be that ratio might be NAN or INF to start with?

Comment: What are some example inputs that cause `NaN` when you don't expect them to?

Comment: Just as a side note, you don't need define `PI` (or pi/2) yourself.  You can use `M_PI_2` defined in `<math.h>` (preferably with either a cast to float or the `f` suffix appended to avoid unnecessary conversions at runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that one of the following is afoot:

- your input value to `ratio` may not be what you expect it to be, and `ratio` itself is possibly `NaN`
- the `cosf` that you're calling isn't the one in `math.h`

Otherwise, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your expression.

Comment: Thanks for your help!   I was off-by-one with my enum that was selecting the easing function, so I was basically debugging the wrong easing function.  This is the bad one and I know why now:

GLfloat circularEaseInOut(GLfloat ratio) {
 return ((ratio *= 2) < 1) ? -0.5*(sqrtf(1-ratio*ratio)-1) : 0.5*(sqrtf(1-(ratio-=2)*ratio)+1);
}

I changed those numbers to floats and everything works now!  Thanks for your help!  I would probably still be chasing that typecasting idea down the rabbit hole.